# RSA Encryption - why does it guarantee a unique cipher?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

In RSA encryption, we use
$c = M^e (mod N)$
where $(e, N)$ is the public key, $M$ is the plaintext message, and $c$ is the encrypted message or ciphertext.

How do we know all message $M$ (for $M<N$) will result in a unique $c$ value?  Isn't it possible there exists two numbers $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M_1^e (mod N) = M_2^3 (mod N)$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you must assume that your parameters are valid RSA, e.g. you must have $c\ne 0$ etc. Let $N=p\times q\;$ with $p,q$ odd primes, the private exponent $d$ with $e d \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi(N)}$, and thus $(M^e)^d \equiv M \pmod N\;$ for all $M$ (here is a [Proof of correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Proofs_of_correctness)).
Now assume 
$$\left(M_1^e\right)^d \equiv\left(M_2^e\right)^d \pmod N.$$ Since we assume valid RSA we have
$$M_1 \equiv \left(M_1^e\right)^d \equiv \left(M_2^e\right)^d \equiv M_2 \pmod N,$$
showing that the plaintexts are identical $\bmod N$ if the cryptotext are the same.